# How can I set responsive image height to 100%?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have the following HTML:

```
<article class="post clearfix">
    <div class="post-img">
        <img src="path/to/img"/>
    </div>
    <div class="post-details">
        [content]
    </div>
</article>
```

And the following CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.post-img { 
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I want the div.post-img to be 100% as tall as its parent article, and for the img inside it to be 100% tall as well. (It's OK if some of the image is clipped off from the left or right sides.)

The height of the article is unknown, so I can't hard code it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why dont you just add height:100%?

Comment: I tried that...it doesn't work. (Assuming you mean I add height: 100% to the .post-img containing div. Is there a style I need to apply to the parent (article) to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this class:

```
.full-height{
    height:100vh; /* 100% vertical view port height */
}
```

for example;

```
<img class="full-height" alt="" src="test.png" />
```

this best way for displaying a full height image.

Comment: Are you suggesting `height: 100%;` or setting `height` explicitly? i.e. image is 400px tall, `height: 400px;`.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport not fully adopted yet, but still a good solution for future web development

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-image` to set an image and `background-size: 100% auto` to the background image size.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option to do that http://jsfiddle.net/237u55q1/1/

```
.post{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.post-img { 
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.33%; 
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
.post-img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.post-details{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 66.66%;
}
```

Add or remove content to see the image adopting to the height :)

Comment: You can also scale the image so that it fits the height by using `width: auto; height: 100%`, and if the image were to be clipped, you could choose to expose the right hand side of the image using `right: 0`, nice answer!